# How to create jniLibs folder on Android Studio?

Tags: android

[image]

Hi, I use Android Studio.

I want to create `jniLibs` folder but my project does not have it.

I know `jniLibs` is created automatically, isn't it?

Is it a `gradle` setting?

Comment: Gradle automatically picks up a jnilibs folder, you just need to make one, but it isn't automatic

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you don't have the JNI directory in your project, do this:

[image]

Comment: strange: the question was about **`jniLibs`** folder, the answer is about **`jni`** folder.

Comment: Well, it fixed the OP problem

Comment: Made my day. Tks

Comment: AS doesn't seem to have this anymore.

Answer (score 3):

@lalongoo gave you the right answer, but you can do this without `Android Studio` :

create a directory named `jni` under `app/src/main` (the default location).