# jniLibs folder showing as cpp folder in Android Studio

Tags: android

I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nv4MEliij14).

I made a folder called jniLibs in app/src/main, and it shows when I see the folder in explorer.

However, when I open up Android Studio, I see that the app folder has 4 folders: manifests, java, cpp, res. Where did the cpp folder come from? Why can't I see the jniLibs folder in Android studio?

Answer (score 11):

I had the exact same problem.

You probably created the JNI folder at first. 
My guess is, Gradle regards the folder contains source files even after you remove the folder and recreates jniLibs folder itself (and adds sourceSets line similar to below code).

Check your build.gradle of the app and find the line

```
sourceSets { main { jni.srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', 'src/main/jniLibs/'] } }
```

under the android section and remove it, Sync, and then all should be ok.

Answer (score 5):

First of all in general you can follow [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38625690/how-to-create-jnilibs-folder-on-android-studio?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) to create the jniLibs folder. I did it twice but in one of these attempts I experienced your same problem

I don't know the inner reason generating this issue but I came up with the following workaround to have `jniLibs` visible [again] in the Android view [tested on Android Studio 3.1.2]

1) at the beginning doing like in the linked answer got me to the point where in my Android view there was only an empty `cpp` folder without any `jni` or `jniLibs` folder visible

[image]

2) at this point I clicked on the cpp folder and I could see the jni folder [red rectangle in the screenshot]

[image]

3) click on it and it will automatically open the Project view where I can see the `jni` folder

[image]

4) right click on it -> Refactor -> Rename... and put jniLibs

[image]

5) now go back on your Android view and surprise!

[image]

Hope that this can help

Answer (score 0):

It should be inside your cpp folder. In Android studio all the cpp related libraries and code(.so files, .a files etc.) resides in cpp folder hence the cpp folder was created.

Comment: Okay, but now I get the following error:

"Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugNdk'.
> Error: Your project contains C++ files but it is not using a supported native build system.
Consider using CMake or ndk-build integration with the stable Android Gradle plugin:
 https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html
or use the experimental plugin:
 http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental."

How do I work around this? I've installed Cmake, ndk, and LLDB

Comment: @HumanCyborgRelations That is a different question man. Consider adding different question for that error. For now what I can tell is that you must use either CMake(CMakeLists.txt build script) or ndk-build(Android.mk build script) way in an order to build your native application in Android Studio. Please go through https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html Please consider **accepting** and **upvoting** the answer if it helped.