# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed android 64 bit processor

Tags: android, loadlibrary, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I am using [this](https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo) library to scan image. Its working well in 32bit android processor but getting error for

```
System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");
```

in 64bit android processor devices.

Getting error,

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/.../base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/.../lib/arm64, /data/app/.../base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libopencv_java3.so"
```

"libs" directory of this project contains file like,

[image: libs file tree]

How can I run this project to scan in both 32 and 64 bit android processor devices?

Comment: If you had a look at the issues logged in the github project, https://github.com/jhansireddy/AndroidScannerDemo/issues/32, someone else has already reported. So basically there is no support for 64 bit devices

Comment: so, is there any other this kind of library available?

Comment: Depends on what you actually want to achieve. I have used Vuforia by Qualcomm to do AR previously.

Answer (score 1):

Actually .so files are supposed to be put under jniLibs not under libs. [Refer to this for more clear answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38625720/5602574) how and where to create